# Show rows that returned zero results with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently working on writing a report for one of our clients.  The report works fine at reporting the number of users per region per course, however the client also wants the courses that have results of zero users to show.  Below is an example:

```
SELECT
lc.code as course_code, count(rc1.region_id) as sc1data, count(rc2.region_id) as
sc2data, count(rc3.region_id) as sc3data, count(rc4.region_id) as sc4data,
count(rc5.region_id) as sc5data, count(rc6.region_id) as sc6data,
count(rc7.region_id) as sc7data, count(rc8.region_id) as sc8data,
count(rc9.region_id) as sc9data, count(rc10.region_id) as sc10data,
count(rc11.region_id) as sc11data, count(rc12.region_id) as sc_total_data

FROM learning_polltrack lpt
LEFT JOIN learning_organization lo ON lo.idOrg = lpt.id_reference
LEFT JOIN learning_course lc ON lc.idCourse = lo.idCourse
LEFT JOIN core_field_userentry cfue ON lpt.id_user = cfue.id_user AND cfue.id_common IN (26)
LEFT JOIN core_field cf ON cf.idField = cfue.id_common
LEFT JOIN core_field_son cfs ON cfs.idField = cfue.id_common AND cfue.user_entry = cfs.idSon
LEFT JOIN provider_type_by_title ptbt ON cfs.translation = ptbt.title
LEFT JOIN core_field_userentry cfue2 ON cfue.id_user = cfue2.id_user AND cfue2.id_common = '15'
LEFT JOIN core_field_son cfs2 ON cfs2.idField = '15' AND cfs2.id_common_son = cfue2.user_entry
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc1 ON rc1.county = cfs2.translation AND rc1.region_id = 1
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc2 ON rc2.county = cfs2.translation AND rc2.region_id = 2
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc3 ON rc3.county = cfs2.translation AND rc3.region_id = 3
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc4 ON rc4.county = cfs2.translation AND rc4.region_id = 4
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc5 ON rc5.county = cfs2.translation AND rc5.region_id = 5
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc6 ON rc6.county = cfs2.translation AND rc6.region_id = 6
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc7 ON rc7.county = cfs2.translation AND rc7.region_id = 7
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc8 ON rc8.county = cfs2.translation AND rc8.region_id = 8
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc9 ON rc9.county = cfs2.translation AND rc9.region_id = 9
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc10 ON rc10.county = cfs2.translation AND rc10.region_id = 10
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc11 ON rc11.county = cfs2.translation AND rc11.region_id = 11
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc12 ON rc12.county = cfs2.translation
WHERE ptbt.provider_type = $P{provider_type} AND lc.code NOT LIKE '6 Month%' AND lc.code NOT LIKE 'F2F%' AND lc.code NOT LIKE 'Beta%' AND lpt.date_attempt BETWEEN $P{From} AND $P{To}

GROUP BY course_code ORDER BY course_code
```

That is my code and the result looks like this:

```
course_code | region 1 | region 2 | region 3 | ...... | region 11 | TOTAL
course 1    |     5    |     0    |    1     |        |     1     |   7
course 2    |     2    |     1    |    0     |        |     1     |   4
course 4    |     3    |     0    |    1     |        |     0     |   4
course 8    |     1    |     0    |    0     |        |     0     |   1
```

But what I need it to look like is:

```
course_code | region 1 | region 2 | region 3 | ...... | region 11 | TOTAL
course 1    |     5    |     0    |    1     |        |     1     |   7
course 2    |     2    |     1    |    0     |        |     1     |   4
course 3    |     0    |     0    |    0     |        |     0     |   0
course 4    |     3    |     0    |    1     |        |     0     |   4
course 5    |     0    |     0    |    0     |        |     0     |   0
course 6    |     0    |     0    |    0     |        |     0     |   0
course 7    |     0    |     0    |    0     |        |     0     |   0
course 8    |     1    |     0    |    0     |        |     0     |   1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all courses, then start the chain of `left outer join` with the list of courses.  I think this is the table that has the alias `lc`.  Instead of this:

```
FROM learning_polltrack lpt
LEFT JOIN learning_organization lo ON lo.idOrg = lpt.id_reference
LEFT JOIN learning_course lc ON lc.idCourse = lo.idCourse
```

Try this:

```
from learning_course lc left outer join
     learning_organizatino lo
     on lc.idCourse = lo.idCourse left outer join
     learning_polltrack lpt
     on lo.idOrg = lpt.id_reference
```

And so on.  My best guess is that courses that have no users have no "polltrack" (whatever that is ;-).  So, they end up missing from the overall join results.

Also, I hope you understand that when you put any table in the `where` clause, it runs the risk of turning the `left join` into an `inner join`.

Comment: This change doesn't help =/ The result stayed the same.

Comment: @dannycodes . . . That leaves the `where` conditions on `ptbt.provider_type` and `lpt.date_attempt` as possible culprits for filtering out the the courses with no users.

Answer (score 0):

Do the count of all rows in a subquery that you left join with the main table. You can pivot the region IDs using `sum(rc.region_id = N)` in the main query.

```
SELECT
    lc.code as course_code,
    ifnull(sum(rc.region_id = 1), 0) sc1data,
    ifnull(sum(rc.region_id = 2), 0) sc2data,
    ...,
    ifnull(sc_total_data, 0) sc_total_data
FROM learning_polltrack lpt
LEFT JOIN learning_organization lo ON lo.idOrg = lpt.id_reference
LEFT JOIN learning_course lc ON lc.idCourse = lo.idCourse
LEFT JOIN core_field_userentry cfue ON lpt.id_user = cfue.id_user AND cfue.id_common IN (26)
LEFT JOIN core_field cf ON cf.idField = cfue.id_common
LEFT JOIN core_field_son cfs ON cfs.idField = cfue.id_common AND cfue.user_entry = cfs.idSon
LEFT JOIN provider_type_by_title ptbt ON cfs.translation = ptbt.title
LEFT JOIN core_field_userentry cfue2 ON cfue.id_user = cfue2.id_user AND cfue2.id_common = '15'
LEFT JOIN core_field_son cfs2 ON cfs2.idField = '15' AND cfs2.id_common_son = cfue2.user_entry
LEFT JOIN region_by_county rc on rc.county = cfs2.translation
LEFT JOIN (select county, count(*) sc_total_data from region_by_county group by region) rcall on rcall.county = cfs2.translation
WHERE ptbt.provider_type = $P{provider_type} AND lc.code NOT LIKE '6 Month%' AND lc.code NOT LIKE 'F2F%' AND lc.code NOT LIKE 'Beta%' AND lpt.date_attempt BETWEEN $P{From} AND $P{To}
GROUP BY course_code ORDER BY course_code
```

Comment: I tried both of your answers and neither made a difference.  The result is still the same not displaying rows with 0 result.

Comment: Try the rewritten query (you'll need to fill in the ellipsis)

Comment: What about LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Lisa They're the same thing.

Comment: Whoops, indeed they are. Would it help if the course table came first?

Comment: This one gives the same result as my original, but it does look cleaner in the joins, so thanks for that =)

Comment: can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're grouping by a column coming from another table that's a left join, and the join condition with `region_by_county` is with the cfs2 table that's also left join.

Comment: One thing I tried to do was use a Union to join a table of the course_codes with all 0 results to that query above, but it just created duplicates of courses when there were results

`SELECT lc2.code as course_code, 0 as sc1data, 0 as sc2data, 0 as sc3data, 0 as sc4data, 0 as sc5data, 0 as sc6data, 0 as sc7data, 0 as sc8data, 0 as sc9data, 0 as sc10data, 0 as sc11data, 0 as sc_total_data
FROM learning_course lc2
WHERE lc2.code NOT LIKE '6 Month%' AND lc2.code NOT LIKE 'F2F%' AND lc2.code NOT LIKE 'Beta%'

UNION ALL`

Comment: No, left join is the appropriate technique, as long as there's a master table that contains all the course codes. Make the fiddle and I'll try to get this working.